# Fila com lista encadeada circular com cabeça

Tags: c

Implemente uma fila em uma lista encadeada circular com cabeça (faça
funçoes que implementam as operacoes de Inserccao e Remocao). O primeiro
elemento da fila ficar´a na segunda celula e o ultimo elemento ficara na celula
anterior a cabeca.

```
Celula *inserir(Celula *fim, Pessoa *p){
    Celula *nova = (Celula*) malloc(sizeof(Celula));
    nova->ptrpessoa = p;
    nova->prox = fim->prox;
    fim->prox = nova;
    fim = nova;
    return fim;
}

void remover(Celula *ini){
    Celula *li = ini->prox;
    ini->prox = li->prox;
    printf("OPA");
    free(li);
}
```

declaração de fila

```
Fila ini;
Fila fim;
```

para ter cabeça eu o que eu faço ?
eu tentei assim.

```
Celula cini, cfim;
ini = &cini;  /aqui o  ini da fila recebe o endereço d cini?
fim = ini; /aqui o  final  da fila recebe o endereço d cini?
```

/e aqui fica circular ?
    ini->prox = ini;

Comment: Suas funções `inserir` e `remover` parecem corretas (depende de como você as está usando, é claro - a `remover` por exemplo remove a próxima depois de `ini`, o que no caso de uma fila está correto). Não entendi muito bem a dúvida: pra ter cabeça, tudo o que você precisa é que o nó inicial/especial não guarde elementos. Como está sua estrutura de dados? (i.e. qual a relação entre `Fila` e `Celula`?)

Comment: Entendi o que tu quis dizer, mas eu queria saber é que o inicio da fila tem que ser dps da cabeça e o final antes queria saber se essa implementação que fiz esta correta nesse aspecto.  cabeca->ini->...->fim->cabeca                          relaçoes struct pessoa{
    char nome[MAX_NOME];
    int num;
};


typedef struct pessoa Pessoa;

struct celula{
  Pessoa *ptrpessoa;
  struct celula *prox;
};

typedef struct celula Celula;

typedef struct celula *Lista;            essas são as relações

Comment: Então, a estrutura é essa mesma, minha dúvida era se `Celula` e `Fila` eram duas coisas diferentes ou não. Só que `ini` é a cabeça ou o primeiro elemento? Sua função `remover` está correta se `ini` for a cabeça, senão está incorreta (vai remover o 2º elemento). A propósito, se a lista fosse duplamente encadeada bastava armazenar a cabeça, mas como não é, é necessário armazenar a cabeça e o último (como você já está fazendo). Enfim, à primeira vista o que você fez está ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, pra lista ter cabeça e ser circular é necessário criar essa cabeça e fazê-la apontar pra si própria. Dinamicamente, seria isso:

```
Celula *cabeca = (Celula*) malloc(sizeof(Celula));
cabeca->prox = cabeca;
```

Segundo, se o que você quer é uma fila, é necessário também guardar uma referência para o último elemento (por eficiência) - que de início é igual à cabeça:

```
Celula *ultimo = cabeca;
```

A partir daí o seu código atual deve funcionar corretamente - `inserir(ultimo, p)` cria um nó depois do último atualizando o mesmo, e `remover(cabeca)` remove o primeiro elemento que não é a cabeça (dica: é interessante verificar também se a fila está vazia - o que ocorre quando `cabeca == ultimo`).

Sua tentativa de declaração, por outro lado, tem alguns pequenos problemas:

```
Celula cini, cfim; // Criou duas células, mas você só precisa de uma
ini = &cini;       // ok
fim = ini;         // ok, mas faltou ini->prox = ini pra ser circular
```

Comment: eu não estava entendendo isso     Celula *nova = (Celula*) malloc(sizeof(Celula));
    nova->ptrpessoa = p;
    nova->prox = fim->prox;
    fim->prox = nova;
    fim = nova;   // não estava entendendo como a cabeça estava apontando para o novo fim só que agora eu entendi eu acho 
    return fim;                                                                                                            é que no meu main tem fim = ini; e ini->prox = ini; então significa que ini->prox= aponta para nova; ? certo?

Comment: A cabeça não aponta pro novo fim, o novo fim é que aponta pra cabeça (em geral, é claro que se a fila tiver só 1 elemento então um aponta pro outro e vice-versa). Seu `main` parece estar certo.